# Want to display date in a label

Tags: java, swing

Can you please help me with this codes, I am trying to show the current date in a label, but am using 3 different class, ie, the main class(AppStart), the class which I create the label in ad it will display the label in the frame, thus the (Swing1) and then the date class it self (DateLabel). The code is shown below:

```
public DateLabel()
{
    Date today = new Date();

    //Date format
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.US);
    String strDate = df.format(today);
     setText( strDate);


}
}

import java.awt.*;//used for Gui Developement
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import javax.swing.*;//Used for GUI development

public class Swing1 extends JFrame
{

JLabel lblWelcome;
DateLabel myDate;
Swing1()
{
    JFrame myJF = new JFrame();
    myJF.setTitle("CBT Tutorial");

    //JLabel Stuff
    myDate = new DateLabel();

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.add(myDate, BorderLayout.NORTH);


    myJF.setSize(300,300);
    myJF.show();

}

}


public class AppStart {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   new Swing1();
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To anyone using netbeans visual builder, I found a faster way to do this.

```
public classname{
    Initcomponents();
    String date= new Date.toString();
    Yourlabelname.setText(date)}
   }
```

Hope it helps a stranded one!:-)

Answer (score 1):

`DateLabel` must extend `JLabel`, otherwise `setText` won't work as well as adding the custom label to the `Container`.

Comment: Whoops, missed that as well. That's the actual problem. The myJF instance doesn't have anything added to it.

Comment: Whoops, missed that as well. You want to use a `BorderLayout` but you miss telling swing to do so. Try `c.setLayout(new BorderLayout())`.

Comment: I used a different approach in my program. I used `String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(new Date()); JLabel label = new JLabel(date);` but its probably more suitable for your Topic than for you question.. :P

Answer (score 1):

No need to create a new JFrame in your Swing1 constructor. Swing1 extends JFrame, just do `getContentPane().add(myDate, BorderLayout.NORTH);` on the Swing1 instance itself. Make sure to call `super()` as the first statement in your constructor, maybe with a suitable argument set (e.g. if you need double buffering or such).